OpenXML sheetprotection removal
I'm experiencing a strange behaviour of OpenXML API.
I need to write a simple application to Lock, Unlock and Check (if Locked/Unlocked) Excel worksheets.
I'm using this code to lock:
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(report, true))
    {
        foreach (var part in document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
        {
            SheetProtection protection = new SheetProtection()
            {
                Sheet = true,
                Objects = true,
                Scenarios = true,
                Password = hexKey
            };
    
            part.Worksheet.InsertAfter(protection, part.Worksheet.Descendants<SheetData>().LastOrDefault());
            part.Worksheet.Save();
        }
    }

this to unlock:
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(report, true))
    {
        foreach (var part in document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
        {
            part.Worksheet.RemoveAllChildren<SheetProtection>();
            part.Worksheet.Save();
        }
    }

and this to check:
    try
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(report, false))
        {
            foreach (var part in document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
            {
                var protections = part.Worksheet.Elements<SheetProtection>();
    
                if (protections.Any())
                    return Protection.Locked;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileFormatException)
    {
        return Protection.Crypted;
    }
    
    return Protection.Unlocked;

It works fine for the amount of test I made except for a single case (where it works partially but I'm not understanding why):
I created an Excel file trough an external application that has a similar feature to lock the file (NI LabView / NI Report Toolkit for Microsoft Office).
If I check the file I find it locked and if I try to unlock it the function work succesfully and following checks returns it as unlocked.
But if I try to open the file with Excel it keeps me asking the password.
I also tried to unpack the Excel file, after unlocking it, and none of the subfiles contains the SheetProtection tag that should be responsible for the sheet protection feature shown by Excel.
So... what I'm missing?
Link to Excel file (password Excel).
Here's the full code repository.
---- EDIT ----
Scavenging into unpacked Excel structure I found that workbook.xml contains a fileSharing node anyway I'm not able to check for the node presence neither to remove it.
Any hint?

The solution was pretty simple:
if (document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.FileSharing != null)
{
   document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.FileSharing.Remove();
   document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
}

